# TortoiseSVN x RiouxSVN (back-up do repositório)

Tags: tortoisesvn

Estou começando a trabalhar com o controle de versão utilizando o TortoiseSVN, e o RiouxSNV como repositório. Acontece que as vezes preciso ficar alguns dias sem acesso a internet, eu eu gostaria de poder exportar todo o repositório para uma pasta local no meu computador, para poder trabalhar offline, e após alguns dias retornar o repositório para o servidor online. Como eu consigo fazer essa cópia de todo o repositório, e não apenas uma cópia de trabalho.
Ah, não tenho problema quando a conflito com outros usuários, pois quando eu for fazer isso ninguém mais estará mexendo no repositório. Então o que preciso na verdade e trocar o repositório de local para online, e vice versa, carregando todo o histórico de modificações.